# iOS app crashes in Guided Access

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I work on a team that has developed an app whose typical use case is to run uninterrupted in Guided Access indefinitely.   In our last release, we've encountered one client that has repeatedly encountered instances of their devices appearing to have our app 'crash to the home screen'.   They stated that despite being on the 'home' screen, the devices (we were told by the client, we were not onsite) were still in Guided Access - which didn't make any sense to us until we were testing the scenario ourselves, running a special build that would force a crash and observing the results.  What we found was:

- after 5 crashes of our app in Guided Access mode (and Guided Access re-starting the app each time as designed), Guided Access would then basically give up and display the keypad to enter a passcode to leave Guided Access.
- if we did not interact with the keypad after a period of time (approx 1 minute), the keypad would go away, and the 'home' screen would be displayed, but the user could not interact with the view other than swipe pagination of the screen to view a second page of app icons.  Touching an app to launch it would result in some animation to recognize the touch but the touched app would not actually launch.   The device then was basically in a bricked state requiring a reset.

We are testing in iOS 8.x.

I've researched online including the Apple developer forums and iOS documentation and have yet to find any explanation of how frequently the 5 crashes must occur (if it is always 5) in order for Guided Access to basically say 'no mas' and prompt the user to exit Guided Access.

So, my question is: Is there a particular velocity of crashes that needs to occur before Guided Access gives up trying to re-start the app?  Is it 5 crashes in 24 hours, a month, or 5 crashes no matter how long it takes to achieve that in a single guided access session?  Our app is typically used for kiosk applications so it is possible for the app to be up indefinitely.  We've confirmed that 5 crashes within 4 hours will indeed create the scenario described above but, rather than testing for days/weeks to get an answer, we figured we'd reach out to the SO community.

Also, I understand the true resolution to the issue is to fix our codebase to prevent the crash - just trying to understand how vulnerable we are to this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get any further with this issue? I think I am having a similar problem.  We have some iPads in Kiosk mode that are occasionally becoming completely disabled and then require restoring.  We have Crashlytics running and no reports are showing a problem (that is flagged anyway)

Comment: I have this same issue, occurring on iOS 10, and 11